# how can I create a gateway like CoinGate to accept any crypto like bitcoin for payment in solidity

Tags: solidity

Could you please explain to me if there is a way to create a contract with solidity to transfer any cryptocurrency or token as payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A contract couldn't interact directly with another blockchain resources.

One option is to use a token that represents the other coin. For example in Ethereum the WBTC token that represents BTC in bitcoin chain.

Another option is to do the conversion on the frontend before sending to the contract.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I convert on the front end? I don't understand. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @SadeqMoballeqoleslam Either use a third party provider like Coingate, Bitpay, etc. or develop yourself those services. Run nodes for each chain you want to support, create a wallet in each chain, then you can receive and send payments in every chain you are supporting.